# JavaScript: Writing multiple functions with Array method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need help with writing multiple, repetitive functions into a one function that passes in variables instead of having to write it over and over again.

Currently, I have JavaScript functions that do the same thing, just with a different variable and strings.

```
var Apple_Data = Info.Apple; // grabs string objects from JSON file
var Banana_Data = Info.Banana; // grabs string objects from JSON file
function CompareApple() {

                if (counter == 0) {
                    prev_Apple_Data = Apple_Data;

                }

                if (Apple_Data > prev_Apple_Data) {
                    if ((Math.abs(Apple_Data - prev_Apple_Data) >= prev_Apple_Data / 2))
                        document.getElementById("Apple_img").src = "img/yelow.png",
                    StartCnt(1);
                    else if ((Math.abs(Apple_Data - prev_Apple_Data) <= prev_Apple_Data / 2))
                        document.getElementById("Apple_img").src = "img/green.png";

                }

                else if (Apple_Data < prev_Apple_Data) {
                    if ((Math.abs(Apple_Data - prev_Apple_Data) >= prev_Apple_Data / 2))
                        document.getElementById("Apple_img").src = "img/yelow.png",
                    StartCnt(1);
                    else if ((Math.abs(Apple_Data - prev_Apple_Data) <= prev_Apple_Data / 2))
                        document.getElementById("Apple_img").src = "img/green.png";
                }

                prev_Apple_Data = Apple_Data;
}

function CompareBanana() {

                if (counter == 0) {
                    prev_Banana_Data = Banana_Data;

                }

                if (Banana_Data > prev_Banana_Data) {
                    if ((Math.abs(Banana_Data - prev_Banana_Data) >= prev_Banana_Data / 2))
                        document.getElementById("Banana_img").src = "img/yelow.png",
                    StartCnt(1);
                    else if ((Math.abs(Banana_Data - prev_Banana_Data) <= prev_Banana_Data / 2))
                        document.getElementById("Banana_img").src = "img/green.png";

                }

                else if (Banana_Data < prev_Banana_Data) {
                    if ((Math.abs(Banana_Data - prev_Banana_Data) >= prev_Banana_Data / 2))
                        document.getElementById("Banana_img").src = "img/yelow.png",
                    StartCnt(1);
                    else if ((Math.abs(Banana_Data - prev_Banana_Data) <= prev_Banana_Data / 2))
                        document.getElementById("Banana_img").src = "img/green.png";
                }

                prev_Banana_Data = Banana_Data;
}
```

If I want to write these in 1 function that passes in variables instead, how will I do it? I was thinking the process would be something such as, having to make 4 different empty arrays

```
Var PreviousData = []; 
Var CurrentData = [];
Var DeclaredData = []; 
Var ImageArray = [];
```

and then write a function that passes in these arrays

```
function Compare(PreviousData, CurrentData, DeclaredData, ImageArray){ 
    if (counter ==0){
        PreviousData = DeclaredData; 
    }
    if (Declared_Data > PreviousData) {
                    if ((Math.abs(Declared_Data - PreviousData) >= PreviousData / 2))
                        document.getElementById("ImageArray").src = "img/yellow.png",
                    StartCnt(1);
                    else if ((Math.abs(Declared_Data - PreviousData) <= PreviousData / 2))
                        document.getElementById("ImageArray").src = "img/green.png";

                }

                else if (Declared_Data < PreviousData) {
                    if ((Math.abs(Declared_Data - PreviousData) >= PreviousData / 2))
                        document.getElementById("ImageArray").src = "img/yellow.png",
                    StartCnt(1);
                    else if ((Math.abs(Declared_Data - PreviousData) <= PreviousData / 2))
                        document.getElementById("ImageArray").src = "img/green.png";
                }
}
```

the counter and the Math.abs is written there to loop through objects and currently works.

and then initialize the function by something like

```
Compare(previousData, info.Apple, DeclaredData, ImageArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code to this:

```
var infoUpd = {
   'prev': false
};

for (key in Info) {
    infoUpd[ key ] = {
        'data': Info[ key ],
        'img': document.getElementById(key+"_img")
    }
}


function compareStuff( key ) {
        var stuffData = infoUpd[ key ];
    if ( infoUpd.prev ) {
        var calcResult = Math.abs(stuffData.data - infoUpd.prev) >= (infoUpd.prev / 2);
        if (stuffData.data !== infoUpd.prev) {
            if ( calcResult ) {
                stuffData.img.src = "img/yelow.png";
            } else {
                stuffData.img.src = "img/green.png";
            }
        }
    }
    infoUpd.prev = stuffData.data; 
}

compareStuff( 'Apple' );
compareStuff( 'Banana' );
```

Comment: This may be a silly question but, on the function compareStuff(stuffData), you're passing in the "stuffData" as a varible ? Where do you declare this?
Also, when the Apple_Data is declared as var Apple_Data, where do you put this inside the function of function compareStuff?

Comment: Yes, as a variable. I declare `Apple_Data` at the top of the script with `var Apple_Data`. Then at the bottom I call `compareStuff` function passing `Apple_Data` to it. In the scope of `compareStuff` function I refer to whatever is passed to this function as `stuffData`. You can change it to whatever you like, you don't need to keep same name, if you pass something to a function explicitly, as argument. But if you refer to something, that lives outside that function, you will refer to it by the exact name, like I do with e.g. `imgSrc` property of the passed object.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, when I print these out by using document.getElementById("compareStuff").innerHTML = Apple_Data, it is only printing out [object] ...

Comment: Change it to `document.getElementById("compareStuff").innerHTML = Apple_Data.data`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. May I please ask , when you declared the variables, why is prev:false, necessary ?

Comment: Because we check that in `compareStuff` function as `if ( stuffData.prev ) {...}` to see if we need to do a comparison at all or we can skip it because there is nothing to compare yet and just assign value to `stuffData.prev` for the first time in `stuffData.prev = stuffData.data` to get ready for the next call of this function.

Comment: Great, I thought, he need to use the same function for multiple purpose with different arguments like: Polymorphism of OOP.

Comment: Nkolay, i've noticed a small problem. The function I have written in my question and the method you have wrote in response does two different thing. The function I have written - the image changes as it loops however, the function you have written does not. Is it a mathematical error?

Comment: No, don't think so. I will rearrange the code. Can you show what you have in `Info` object? You can add `console.dir(Info);` e.g. before `function compareStuff(stuffData) {..}` declaration and then look it up in Chrome console, which will open in the bottom of Chrome if you press F12.

Comment: Info object is declared within the function json(){ as var Info = response[counter];}, and the function compareStuff() is within this function json(). 

function json(); loops through the strings within the json file in format of, for example: "Apple" : 23.48. 

When I write console.dir(Info); before function compareStuff(stuffData) and press f12, it is outputting "object"

Comment: says "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" for the line "infoUpd.prev = stuffData.data;"

Comment: It works here - https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/esnfauwm/. Can you check the code again?

Comment: got ya, so, to get it from the external json file, itd be something like
var apple_data
{ prev: false, 
imgSrc: document.getElementById("apple_img").src, 
data: Info.ROP};

Comment: Can you explain it a bit? I thought you get `Info` object which will have e.g. `"Apple" : 23.48`, `Banana" : 01.11`. In the fiddle I then turn this into another object to handle in that function. And I keep `prev` outside the individual `apple` and `banana` keys to have correct access to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103451/discussion-between-axchink-and-nikolay-ermakov).

Answer (score 1):

Default function parameters allow formal parameters to be initialized with default values if no value or undefined is passed. You can use this properties to accomplish your complete work.
**Lets have a look with different example:**

```
function setBackgroundColor(element, color = 'rosybrown') {
  element.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

setBackgroundColor(someDiv);            // color set to 'rosybrown'
setBackgroundColor(someDiv, undefined); // color set to 'rosybrown' too
setBackgroundColor(someDiv, 'blue');    // color set to 'blue'
```

Here i use a function `setBackgroundColor` to style the background color of element. You can do it for your purpose.

For more details visit [default_parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters)

Comment: Can you please clarify what browsers currently support this functionality?

Comment: @NikolayErmakov, from where the `"browsers currently support this functionality?"` comes??, its just an example how `axchink` can do this job.

Comment: I afraid what the functionality you suggest can hardly help him do his job due to a very limited browser support at this time. You will notice that if you scroll the page you linked to the bottom. Or can he do this outside a browser?